# stdin: is not a tty connection closed SSH

Tags: ssh, terminal

I have not been able to SSH into my server for about 6 months if not more. The connection is made, however, it closes with the msg

**stdin: is not a tty**

googled this error, attempted some of the fixes that some have posted, however, nothing has worked for me. Asked my server support yet they don't understand anything.

Any assistance would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Try at least to require a tty

```
ssh -t remoteUser@remoteServer
```

Check your remote `.bahsrc` or `.profile`, to ensure they are not expecting anything on stdin.

The [OP erezmed](https://stackoverflow.com/users/13783949/erezmed) points out [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62493723/stdin-is-not-a-tty-connection-closed-ssh/62497959#comment110681332_62497959):

> I have reason to believe that the older deprecated Lentos 6 might have cause this issue lately after the discontinued it.

Comment: Thank you @VonC that was one of the first things I have tried, which works and allows me access to my server through SSH, however, with a limited capacity and without a shell prompt. That was fine for tending to menial tasks but I would require more. I purchase a new server which is updated to Centos 7.8, the ssh worked very well as it used to work on my old server. I have reason to believe that the older deprecated Lentos 6 might have cause this issue lately after the discontinued it.

Comment: @ErezMed Thank you for your feedback. I have included the relevant part of your comment  in the answer for more visibility.